# Converting Array of Objects into Array of Arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, client-side

I am hoping somebody will point me in right direction here. I have an Array with number of objects that have Date, Set and Value as Properties.
I need to convert this on client side to an Array of Arrays where each member Array holds data like this: [ Date, Value of Set 0, Value of Set 1 ]
I'm looking for a solution that will work with any number of "Sets", which is the part that makes it complicated for me. Any proposed solution may require jQuery or some other javascript library set you use to get this done. I don't have a problem with that, let's just get it done. :)
Please refer to initial and end data sets below:

First one is with just two sets:

```
var data = [  
    { Date: "2/10/2013", Set: 0, Value: 1 },   
    { Date: "2/10/2013", Set: 1, Value: 0 },   
    { Date: "2/11/2013", Set: 0, Value: 15 },   
    { Date: "2/11/2013", Set: 1, Value: 8 },   
    { Date: "2/12/2013", Set: 0, Value: 12 },    
    { Date: "2/12/2013", Set: 1, Value: 11 },    
    { Date: "2/13/2013", Set: 0, Value: 15 },   
    { Date: "2/13/2013", Set: 1, Value: 19 },   
    { Date: "2/14/2013", Set: 0, Value: 10 },    
    { Date: "2/14/2013", Set: 1, Value: 20 }   
];

var endData = [
    [ "2/10/2013", 1, 0 ],  
    [ "2/11/2013", 15, 8 ],  
    [ "2/12/2013", 12, 11 ],  
    [ "2/13/2013", 15, 19 ],  
    [ "2/14/2013", 10, 20 ]  
];
```

And here is an example of 3 sets.
So, for example if data was like this:

```
var data = [
    { Date: "2/10/2013", Set: 0, Value: 1 },   
    { Date: "2/10/2013", Set: 1, Value: 2 },  
    { Date: "2/10/2013", Set: 2, Value: 3 },   
    { Date: "2/11/2013", Set: 0, Value: 10 },  
    { Date: "2/11/2013", Set: 1, Value: 15 },   
    { Date: "2/11/2013", Set: 2, Value: 20 }  
];
```

Returned array would need to be like this:

```
var endData = [  
    [ "2/10/2013", 1, 2, 3 ],  
    [ "2/10/2013", 10, 15, 20 ]  
];
```

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: If it's an option, consider converting it to an object, keyed on the date string instead. `{"2/10/2013": [1,2,3], "2/11/2013": [10,15,20]}`

Comment: I consider the original format to be better. Your end arrays contain two types of data, when they should (for "grammatical" reasons) only contain one type. There's no reason you can't loop through the objects just as easily as you would loop through the arrays.

Comment: That said: what have you tried?

Comment: @Blazemonger, it does need to be in that format. I wouldn't ask this without reason. If you look at https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart
It's expecting data as an Array of Arrays which it later converts into DataTable.

Comment: @crush, I have data the way it is, without ability to change what's coming from server side, but I agree, that would solve my problem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;(function() {
    var data = [  
        { Date: "2/10/2013", Set: 0, Value: 1 },   
        { Date: "2/10/2013", Set: 1, Value: 0 },   
        { Date: "2/11/2013", Set: 0, Value: 15 },   
        { Date: "2/11/2013", Set: 1, Value: 8 },   
        { Date: "2/12/2013", Set: 0, Value: 12 },    
        { Date: "2/12/2013", Set: 1, Value: 11 },    
        { Date: "2/13/2013", Set: 0, Value: 15 },   
        { Date: "2/13/2013", Set: 1, Value: 19 },   
        { Date: "2/14/2013", Set: 0, Value: 10 },    
        { Date: "2/14/2013", Set: 1, Value: 20 }   
    ];

    var endData = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        var date = data[i].Date;

        if (endData[date] === undefined)
            endData[date] = [];

        endData[date].push(data[i].Value);
    }

    var finalData = [];

    for (var ed in endData) {
        var a = [ed];

        for (var i = 0; i < endData[ed].length; ++i) {
            a.push(endData[ed][i]);
        }

        finalData.push(a);
    }

    console.log(finalData);
})();
```

The output looks like:

```
var finalData = [
    ["2/10/2013", 1, 0],
    ["2/11/2013", 15, 8],
    ["2/12/2013", 12, 11],
    ["2/13/2013", 15, 19],
    ["2/14/2013", 10, 20]
];
```

Comment: Trying this out. Give me a second. 
EDIT: This works! Very much appreciated.

Comment: I want it reverse means how to convert array of array into array of objects in javascript

Answer (score 4):

Use a loop and a global `dat` variable to keep track of where you are in the list:

```
var endData=[], dat='', row=[];
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    var obj=data[i], val=obj.Value;
    if (dat!=obj.Date) {
        if (i) endData.push(row);
        dat = obj.Date;
        row = [dat, val];
    } else {
        row.push(val);
    }
}
endData.push(row); // last one
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/rgJbq/

Comment: This one is definitely more concise, and only loops over the data once, so I imagine performs better. I have checked that it is outputting the right result. Nice work.

Comment: Does this require them to be sorted by date in the `data` array?

Comment: @crush Yes, just like the examples the OP provided.

Comment: I want it reverse means how to convert array of array into array of objects in javascript

Answer (score 1):

```
var endData = [];
var indexes = {};

for(var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
    if(indexes[data[i].Date] === undefined) {
        indexes[data[i].Date] = endData.length;
        endData.push([data[i].Date]);
    }
    endData[indexes[data[i].Date]][data[i].Set + 1] = data[i].Value;
}
```

Comment: This one produces the correct result as well, but I'm not sure if it is also dependent on pre-sorted values.